# How to check which graphic card is used by the system?

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, intel-graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have laptop with two graphic cards one build in Intel and the other is nvidia GeForce. I've installed Xubuntu 16.04 and now I want to check which graphic card is used by the system. Probably build in because there are not drivers for Nvidia but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`inxi` is a helpful little system info tool that collects all kinds of information about your soft- and hardware and outputs the user relevant pieces in a nice and understandable format.

You install it using `sudo apt-get install inxi`.

Then you can run `inxi -G` to print graphics related information.

Here's an example from my hardware:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.03hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 940M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.44
```

You see I have a built-in Intel graphics chip and an Nvidia chip. The active device is my Nvidia chip.

Comment: I already have inxi installed after fresh install of Xubuntu.

Comment: How do you know NVIDIA is the running card?

Comment: @AdiYono It is referred to in the `GLX Renderer:` line.