# Black screen when login graphic mode after changing the setting of graphic cards

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I changed my setting and switched from an NVIDIA graphic card to an Intel Card. After that, I can log in text mode only. Every time I tried to login graphic mode, only a black screen appeared.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. From the text mode, I typed inxi -G and here is the output:

```
Graphics:   Card-1: Intel Device 3e92
            Card-2: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
            Display Server: X.org 1.20.5 drivers: 1915,nouveau tty size: 240x67 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
```

According to this post: [How to check which graphic card is used by the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831893/how-to-check-which-graphic-card-is-used-by-the-system?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=ec5e047483e94249845caf3ecf6ceda2)
, I expected that I will see GLX Renderer, but nothing like that appeared, so it seems like neither Intel or NVIDIA graphic card is selected and that is the reason why I see the black screen in the graphic mode only? I am very newbie to Ubuntu. Can anyone please help me how to fix the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: How did you switch the cards? Did you use `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-settings`?

Comment: @Samuel I played with BIOS setting and I remembered there were an option to either boot from Intel or boot from NVIDIA. The default setting was NVIDIA, but I changed it to Intel. And after that I could not log in graphic mode anymore.

Comment: so I tried prime-select nvidia and then prime-select query, the output is nvidia. That means nvidia graphic card is selected. After that I reboot my system, but still the black screen appear, that means somehow the graphic card is still not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My monitor does not compatible with the graphic card inserted in the CPU. My monitor is full HD but the graphic card wants to render Quad HD.